# MySQL alter table change or modify when changing size of column

Tags: mysql

I have a huge table (10GB+).
Some developers made a mistake to add a bigint(250) column.
I want to bring it back to bigint(8)

When I use the MODIFY statement it is a lot faster than using CHANGE

```
alter table persons modify PersonId bigint(8) auto_increment;
```

is faster than

```
alter table persons change PersonId PersonId bigint(8) auto_increment;
```

My opinion on this is that change is rebuilding the table and modify not.
But what is modify doing exactly (under the hood) in this case?

Comment: `bigint(250)` to `bigin(8)` changes _nothing_ about the data: it's only a hint for representation, the storages needs etc. are the same, as it remains a `bigint`, so the data does not need to be altered, just some fancy definition of the table itself, which should be very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MODIFY will not attempt to rename the column. CHANGE will attempt to rename even if the target name is the same as the current name, this is most likely the reason why it takes a little more time.